# CSS/HTML Help - Trying to get a div to float to the left but only in the non-mobile version of the sight. Mockup image and code are attached

Tags: html, css

Is there something that I put under the "@media screen..."?

**CSS:**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
html {
  max-width: 320px;
}

/* Default styles first then media queries */
@media screen and (min-width: 400px)  
@media screen and (min-width: 600px)  
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) 
@media screen and (min-width: 1400px)
.container { float : right;}
/*top part*/
.Banner img{

width: 100%

}

h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #660066;
    background-color:  #ffccdc
;
}
header {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    color: #636;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #CCF;
}



/* body style */
body {
    background-color:  #ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:80%;
    color:#234;
}


/*button styles, navigation*/

button:hover {background-color: #B33EB2;}

.button {
    background-color: #ffccdc;
    border: none;
    color: #660066;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}








ul {

    list-style-type: none;

    margin: 0;

    padding: 0;

}



li {

    display: inline;

}


/*main*/

#content {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#form {
text-align: left;
float: left;
}

/*footer styles*/

footer {
    background-color: #E3A6CA;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#container footer p {
    margin: 0px;
    color: #606;
}
```

**Here is the HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--Phoebe Narita-->
<link href="Pnarita-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><header>

<title>Phoebe Narita Homepage</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Phoebe Narita desktop">



</header>
<body>



    <div class="Banner">
            <a href="/"><img src="images/Banner.jpg" alt="Banner"></a>
    </div>

    <br>



    <a href="homepage.html"><img src="images/PhoebeNaritacandy.jpg" width="150" height="200" alt="Logo"></a>


<nav id="primary_nav">

 <ul>
  <li><a href="homepage.html" class="button"><h2>Home</h2></a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html" class="button"><h2>Contact</h2></a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>



    <main>
        <h2>Contact Me</h2>


        <p>Required information marked with an asterisk (*)</p>

        <form method="post" action="http://webdevbasics.net/scripts/prime.php">
            <label for="myName">*Name:</label>
    <br>

            <input type="text" name="myName" id="myName" required="required"><br>
            <label for="myEmail">*E-mail:</label>
<br>
            <input type="email" name="myEmail" id="myEmail" required="required"><br>
            <label for="mytel">*Phone:</label>
<br>
            <input type="tel" name="mytel" id="mytel" required="required"><br>
            <label for="myComments">*Message:</label>
<br>
            <textarea name="myComments" id="myComments" rows="2" cols="20" required="required"></textarea><br>
        <input id="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Send Now">

        </form>


<div class="container">

<p>Please visit any of my social networking pages for shows/event info.</p><br>


<p>I'm sorry, but I am currently unavailable for any design/commissioned work.</p><br>


<p>My inbox gets flooded regularly and I try to keep up as best I can with replies.
If I have not responded to your email within a few months, please resend it as it may have been lost in the madness. Thank you!</p>

</div> 

</main>

<div class="footer">

<div class="footer-content">


<h2>Quick Links</h2>

<ul>

  <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
</div>

<div class="footer-content">

<h2>Social Links</h2>

<ul>

    <li>Facebook</li>

    <li>Instagram</li>

    <li>Tumblr</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2016 Phoebe Narita</p><br>
    <a href="mailto:phoebe@narita.com">phoebe@narita.com</a>

</body>

</html>
```

**This is a mock-up of what I am aiming for it to look like**:

[image]

The information in  is what I want to be in the red circle.

Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for your `@media` rules aren't correct (you for got your `{...}`).

From **[W3S](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp):**

```
@media not|only mediatype and (media feature) {
    CSS-Code;
}
```

A real world example would be:

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

When the [viewport](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) is `480px` or more the `body` element will have a `background-color` of `light green`. If the viewport is smaller than that, it's `background-color` will be `red`.

If you wanted to make an element `float` only on *"non-mobile"* viewports, you will first need to decide how *"non-mobile"* translates into viewport size in `pixels`. Let's pretend that size is **`600px`**.

```
.foo {
  float: none; //this is default, but showing it for example purposes
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        .foo {
            float: left;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I will try this later and see if I can figure it out :)

Comment: @MatthewSchwer Glad to help! I see you're new here, if you feel that my answer solves your issue be sure to mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.